# Можно ли получить список участников в вк, кто лайкнул фото в абоме группы, но не является ее участником?

Tags: вконтакте

Можно ли получить список участников в вк, кто лайкнул фото в альбоме группы, но не является ее участником, если я не администратор группы?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `vk.api`, например `likes.getList` и `groups.getMembers`, а уже на основании полученных коллекций можно легко получить свою

Comment: По-любому как-то можно, на сайте это же показывается.

Answer (score 4):

Да, можно

Пример на `Python`.
Для него Вам нужно будет установить библиотеку `vk_api`:

```
pip install vk_api
```

Если у Вас **Windows**:

```
python.exe -m pip install vk_api
```

Далее Вам надо будет создать скрипт с таким исходным кодом:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import vk_api
vk = vk_api.VkApi(login='login', password='password')
vk.auth()
api = vk.get_api()

def get_members(group_id):
    count = 1000
    offset = 0
    while count == 1000:
        res = api.groups.getMembers(count=1000, offset=1000*offset, group_id=group_id)
        count = res['count']
        offset += 1
        yield res['items']

def in_file(filename, user_id):
    with open(filename) as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            if user_id == line.strip():
               return True
    return False


likers = api.likes.getList(...)  # см. комментарии после кода
with open('temp.txt', 'w') as file:
    for line in get_members('<group_id>'):
        for one in line:
            file.write(str(one)+'\n')
res = []
for liker in likers:
    if not in_file('temp.txt', str(liker)):
        res.append(liker)

print(res)
```

Параметры к getList подсмотрите [здесь](https://vk.com/dev/likes.getList).